# my flutter app restarting after setting wallpaper on screen in android 12

Tags: flutter, dart

**App Restart**
app is working fine on android 10 and 11 but on android 12 it crases after setting wallpaper on home screen.
give me your valuable answer if you know about this issue\

Comment: can you post stacktrace when the app crashes?

Comment: i used in anothe app same issue also their for android 12

Comment: Future<void>setwallpaper()async{


    try{
      // String url = widget.lower;  // Image url
    //widget.image has been taken from last screen as a parameter,and set as wallpaper
      var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(widget.image);  //image file

      int location = WallpaperManager.BOTH_SCREEN;  //Choose screen type

      String result = (await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(file.path, location)) as String;

    }catch(e){
      Get.snackbar(e.toString(), e.toString());
    }

Comment: flutter_wallpaper_manager: ^0.0.3
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0

Comment: Alright but is there any stacktrace you could see in logcat or console when the app crashes?

Comment: **Stacktrace show me these lines**      E/BLASTBufferQueue(16415): BLASTBufferItemConsumer::onDisconnect()
D/OplusScrollToTopManager(16415): unregisterGuidePopupDismissReceiverInSystemUI
D/OplusScrollToTopManager(16415): Receiver not registered: android.view.OplusScrollToTopManager$1@b522a1c
D/OplusScrollToTopManager(16415): unregisterSystemUIBroadcastReceiver 
D/OplusScrollToTopManager(16415): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.view.OplusScrollToTopManager$2@878a625
V/OplusZoomWindowDecorViewHelper(16415): removeZoomView